# Magento 1 Embedded ERP Removed but AdvancedStock still called

Tags: magento

I attempted to remove the Embedded ERP from my website. Everything worked smoothly except som SQL stuff. But when a customer attempts to add an item to their cart, the flash loads forever and the System.log throws the following.

> ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/AdvancedStock/Helper/Product/Base.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /var/www/phono.dk/public_html/subdomains/dev/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>   on line 94 ERR (3): Warning:
>   include(Mage/AdvancedStock/Helper/Product/Base.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /var/www/phono.dk/public_html/subdomains/dev/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>   on line 94 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'Mage/AdvancedStock/Helper/Product/Base.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/var/www/phono.dk/public_html/subdomains/dev/app/code/local:/var/www/phono.dk/public_html/subdomains/dev/app/code/community:/var/www/phono.dk/public_html/subdomains/dev/app/code/core:/var/www/phono.dk/public_html/subdomains/dev/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in
>   /var/www/phono.dk/public_html/subdomains/dev/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>   on line 94

I have no idea what's still calling for AdvancedStock, but whatever does it shouldn't. Any suggestions as to what that might be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Perhaps, although the question is code related, but I am posting it on stackexchange instead. Thanks.

Comment: I agree it is code-related, but it isn't programming-related.